# Fold selected lines

Tags: visual-mode, folding

How can I fold and unfold lines selected in visual mode?

Lets say I have three paragraphs and I want to fold the first or last two into one line:

```
Test
====
Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos
de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias..

Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos
de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias..

Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos
de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias..
```

`za` folds only one paragraph.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can press <kbd>V</kbd> to go into Visual Line mode, select the lines to be folded, then <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> to make a manual fold.  You'll need to `:set foldmethod=manual` if it isn't already set.

You can open the fold with <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>, or delete the fold with <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>.

Comment: I get error message ``E350: Cannot create fold with current 'foldmethod'`` after pressing keys ``zf``.

Comment: @niekas: Set `foldmethod` to `manual` first.

Comment: I got one more problem. I have ``.rst`` file with section ``Test\n====``. When I select several paragraphs of this section and press ``zf`` all section gets folded instead of the selected paragraphs. How do I turn this automation off?

Comment: If a new fold you are trying to create partially overlaps with an existing open fold, then closing the new fold will cause overlapping folds to close too. You may need to delete some folds using `zd` first.

Comment: May I ask, after using `zf` to fold a few sections, then moved the cursor out of those sections, why I cannot use `zr` to unfold all sections? Thank you.

Comment: @midnite If you have a question, please post it as a question.